# Create a histogram with N buckets of interval X where the last bucket also includes the counts greater than its interval

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have objects where every object has a nonnegative "weight" field. i want to sort the objects into 10 weight classes of interval 100, i tried putting in the "aggs" field, the following:

```
        "aggs":{
          "weights":{
            "histogram":{
              "interval":100,
              "field":"weight"
            }
          }
        }
```

But this would give me every interval of 100, e.g.(starting interval : doc_count)

(0 : 3) (100 : 5) ... (900 : 3) (1000 : 2) (1100 : 5)

What I would like instead is

(0 : 3) (100 : 5) ... (900 : 10) where 10 comes from the bucket itself and all buckets after it

I tried using the `range` feature: `"range":{"weight":{"to":"1000"}}` but that ignores all the buckets that come after the 10th one. Is this possible with the histogram feature on elastic? Or would this require something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in the **count** of the buckets (and not, say, the sum of all `weights`), you could force all values above 900 into the last bucket using a [range aggregation value script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html#_value_script):

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "weight_ranges": {
      "range": {
        "field": "weight", 
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "_value <= 900 ? _value : 900"
        },
        "ranges": [
          { "to": 100 },
          { "from": 100, "to": 200 },
          { "from": 200, "to": 300 },
          { "from": 300, "to": 400 },
          { "from": 400, "to": 500 },
          { "from": 500, "to": 600 },
          { "from": 600, "to": 700 },
          { "from": 700, "to": 800 },
          { "from": 800, "to": 900 },
          { "from": 900 }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you're dynamically generating these histograms and the value `900` is arbitrary / parametrizable, you could [store the script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#modules-scripting-stored-scripts) like so:

```
POST _scripts/histogram_cutoff
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "_value <= params.cutoff ? _value : params.cutoff"
  }
}
```

and then reference it in any subsequent query by its ID:

```
POST weights/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "weight_ranges": {
      "range": {
        "field": "weight", 
        "script": {
          "id": "histogram_cutoff",     <--
          "params": {
            "cutoff": 900
          }
        },
        "ranges": [
          { "to": 100 },
          ...
          { "from": 900 }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```